# dnn search removal of update and source

Tags: search, dotnetnuke, field

I'm looking to modify the returned search results in a standard dnn installation. Currently it's displaying the page, updated & source.

I need to remove the last two fields. How can this be done??

Thanks

Comment: What version of DNN are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do it.  The "Fastest" would be to add this to your portal.css or other .css file

```
.dnnSearchResultItem-Others {display: none;}
```

Otherwise, I believe you can manage this with the localization files, but I haven't checked yet.